# Difference between double- precision data type and numeric data type

Tags: r, precision

What is the difference between double-precision data type and numeric data type in R programming?

Answer (score 15):

From [stat.ethz.ch:](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/double.htm)

> It is a historical anomaly that R has two names for its floating-point vectors, double and numeric (and formerly had real).
>   double is the name of the type. numeric is the name of the mode and also of the implicit class. As an S4 formal class, use "numeric".
>   The potential confusion is that R has used mode "numeric" to mean ‘double or integer’

We can think of doubles as belonging to numeric. To see this:

```
 > is.double(1)
 [1] TRUE
 > is.numeric(1)
 [1] TRUE
```

R normally stores numbers as doubles. Using "numeric()" is the same as "double()." You can also store a number as a single or an integer. Both will be numeric. You may choose to force a number be stored as an integer for performance reasons, but unless you are building a package the trade offs might not be worth your time.

I suggest reading [Gillespie's Overview](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/7-1-data-types.html) for more info on type and performance.

Comment: "[Gillespie's Overview](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/)" referenced above gives HTTP 404, probably because the online book was revised.

Answer (score 1):

@tk3: numeric is NOT always identical to double (and real).

```
> x <- 10
> storage.mode(x)
[1] "double"
> is.numeric(x)
[1] TRUE
> x <- as.integer(x)
> storage.mode(x)
[1] "integer"
> is.numeric(x)
[1] TRUE
```